# How to use filter, count, sort, max and groupby with a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark to try to use filter, group by, sort, count and max methods to filter the data that is in a dataframe. I have this SQL select that I am trying to duplicate with pyspark and get the same results with:

```
select lab_org, COUNT(DISTINCT lab_id) as lab, MAX(day) as frequency, SUM(total) as total FROM lab_data GROUP BY lab_org ORDER BY frequency, lab, total DESC
```

Sample output would look like something like this:

```
lab_org lab frequency   total
370     133 556         3386.78
1031    146 557         4232.12
2092    122 559         2290.54
1468    81  568         4131.73
2254    80  569         1270.35
```

I am new to pyspark and struggling where to start.  Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Pyspark doesn't support distinct count on group aggregations, however that can still be obtained by:

```
df.select('lab_id').distinct().count()
```

Other than that, I've tried to come close to your query:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['lab_org']).agg({'lab_id':'count', 'frequency':'max', 'total':'sum'}).orderBy(['max(frequency)', 'count(lab_id)', 'sum(total)'])
new_df.show()
```

Comment: `pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct(col, *cols)`